# POST Data Azure Function

Tags: mongodb, azure-functions

I am using Azure Function as a POST API to post the body to an MongoDB. With the code below

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    await client.connect();
    const database = client.db("test");
    const collection = database.collection("notes");
    await collection.insertOne(req.body)
}
```

Everything is working in debug mode, I checked with POSTman but once I send the code to deploy on Azure, the post does not work, and I get this html page? I don't understand
[image]

Comment: From the response size it seems you're getting the default Azure "Your function app is up and running" page. Make sure you're posting to the correct endpoint url.

Comment: You're right wrong URL

Comment: @NicolasTang. Could you please post the answer as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong URL endpoint
Thanks [Max Ivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2579733/max-ivanov)